# How to do Class Loading in Tomcat

Tags: apache, hibernate

How to do Class Loading in Tomcat 
In my web app folder I have deployed a war and in that war there are some libraries which are clashing with my tomcat lib folder. Also, I don't want to remove any of my libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not ready to remove your libraries you can go on with removing those package with Tomcat AS.
But could you be more accurate in your description.
What are libraries that leads to conflicts? What are you packging in your war file?